# Why is my header not set with beforSend method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to make an ajax request with that bit of code : (separate file that I load in the html)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#loadDeviceBtn').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        createTableIfNotExist();

        var device = $('#devices-search').val();
        console.log(device);

        getTopicsForDevice(device);
    });

});

function createTableIfNotExist() {
    if (!$('#table').length) {
        $('.card-body').append("<div id=\"table\"><table><thead><tr><th>Topic</th><th>Value</th></tr></thead></table></div>");
    }
}

function getTopicsForDevice(device) {
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"api_url",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function (request, settings) {
            console.log(settings.url);
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer reallylongtoken");
        }
    });
}
```

But I keep getting an 403 error, and when I look at the request headers the Authorization one I tried to set is not there. But I know the function is called because the log appear.

Little detail that might be of importance... My IDE (IntelliJ) is not coloring the ajax word in yellow and the beforeSend word neither like it uses to do in other working project.

Comment: what is running on server side PHP & Apache ?

Comment: spring boot so java and tomcat... But it will run on wildfly afterwards

Comment: the Authorization header is being sent as I check in Browser Dev tool. I think  you should debug on server level.

Comment: I tested the token with Postman and the same request and it works fine